# Sequilize: insert or update on table \"tokens\" violates foreign key constraint \"tokens_userId_fkey\

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I dont why I keep getting this error and I cant trace the constraint that I am violating.
My two tables are `Token` and `User` and as you can see from the code below, they linked together through `userId`. I get the error trying to create a new table for `Token` using the `userId` value from User

TOKEN TABLE

```
Token.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            userId: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
            },
            refreshToken: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: Date.now(),
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: Date.now(),
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'token',
        }
    );
```

USER TABLE

```
User.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                unique: true,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            username: {
                type: STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            email: {
                type: STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            password: {
                type: STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            inactive: {
                type: BOOLEAN,
                defaultValue: true,
            },
            activationToken: {
                type: STRING,
            },
            passwordResetToken: {
                type: STRING,
            },
            image: {
                type: STRING,
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: Date.now(),
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: Date.now(),
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'user',
        }
    );
```

RELATIONSHIP

```
    User.hasMany(Token, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
    Token.belongsTo(User);
```

CREATING TOKEN TABLE

```
public static async register(userInputDTO: IUserInputDTO) {
        const { email, password, username } = userInputDTO;

        Logger.silly('Hashing password');
        const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(password);
        const user = { username, email, password: hashedPassword, activationToken: AuthService.generateToken(16) };
        const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
        const userRecord = await db.user.create(user, { transaction: t });

        try {
            EmailService.sendAccountActivation(email, user.activationToken);
            const userJson = userRecord.toJSON();
            const token = generateToken(String(userJson.id));
            Logger.silly('Creating token');
            await db.token.create({
                userId: String(userJson.id),
                refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
            });
            EmailService.sendAccountActivation(email, user.activationToken);

            return {
                user,
                token,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            // Error handling
            t.rollback();
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `foreignKey` option should be the same in both paired associations:

```js
Token.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

Second, you forgot to indicate in `db.token.create` call the same transaction as you used in the `db.user.create`:

```js
await db.token.create({
  userId: String(userJson.id),
  refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
}, { transaction: t } );
```